# Marklogic as LOGIN SERVER

Tags: authentication, marklogic

I have one application, which has login page and which takes username and password and based upon role , it will show respective page.

Now we are using marklogic, and we have stored users in marklogic.
And i want to do authenticate user and their roles based upon marklogic database. Also i have ldap comfiguration with marklogic.

Please give stepwise explanation and code . It will be great help..

Answer (score 2):

This is described in great detail in the documentation.
Start here:   https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:login

Then work your way through this guide:  https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/security
There isn't a one-size-fits-all 'stepwise explanation and code'